# Having a segmentation fault

Tags: c

So im having a segmentation fault that is called out at the

```
while(root->next != NULL)
```

here is my code.

```
void findFlight(Queue *q,int flightNum){
    qNode *root = (qNode *)malloc(sizeof(qNode));
    root = q->front;
    printf("\n %s",root->fullName);
    FILE *fp = fopen("flightnumber.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("\nFile could not be opened");
        return;
    }
    while(root->next != NULL){

        if(root->flightNum == flightNum){
            fprintf(fp,"%s is taking flight %d",root->fullName,root->flightNum);
            printf("%s is taking flight %d",root->fullName,root->flightNum);
        }

        root = root->next;
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I can already see a red flag. You allocate a `qNode`, but then immediately discard that pointer in favour of `q->front`. What's up with that? Furthermore, you don't check if the file can be read, by making sure it hasn't hit `EOF` yet.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, we don't know how the function is called and what `q` is set to.

Comment: You set `root` in the declaration: `qNode *root = (qNode *)malloc(sizeof(qNode));`, then immediately you overwrite `root` with the statement `root = q->front;`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the comments:

- we have little understanding about what is guaranteed about `q` (or what `qNode` or `Queue` look like)
- `root` is allocated at the start of the function but the pointer value get replaced by `q->front`, causing a memory leak, could probably be detected by your compiler by enabling warnings.
- is `q` or `q->front` not `NULL` ?
- please check if `root` is not `NULL` before checking `root->next`
- ending if `root->next` is `NULL` would mean that the last node ( with content ) will be skipped because it does not have a `next` ( trace your algorithm by hand to verify )

suggested fixes (file output skipped for brevity):

```
void findFlight(Queue *q, int flightNum){
  if( q == NULL ) return;
  qNode *current = q->front;
  if( current == NULL ) return;
  while(current != NULL) {
      if( current->flightNum == flightNum ) {
          // we assume that current->fullName is actually set, but feel free to verify
          fprintf(stdout, "%s is taking flight %d", current->fullName, current->flightNum);
      }
      current = current->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: turns out the issue is i was freeing up char *token that was never initialized in a different function causing the segmentation fault. Also was wondering why do new programmers questions get so heavily downvoted?

Comment: Because you formulated your question wrongly, as you pointed out the issue came from a different function, without a good picture of what is your issue such question would hardly help other people that are looking for an answer. Question score are more an indicator of the question quality than an assessment of the one asking the question.  
Also these issue would be easier to pinpoint with the use of a debugger, which would usually take less effort than asking the question on this site